# Adding Icons to Combobox Items such that Icons are visible at the Right Side

Tags: qt

I am working on an application in which I need to show the List of Program Names and corresponding Icons in a Combobox Popup Menu.

I tried following things:
a. Created the Custom Widget deriving from QCombobox
b. ReImplemented the showPopup() function as follows

```
void CMyComboBox::showPopup() 
{
    QComboBox::showPopup(); 
    mp_Popup = this->findChild<QFrame *>(); 
    mp_Popup->move( mp_Popup->x(), mp_Popup->y() - this->height() - mp_Popup->height() );
}
```

c. Adding Items to Combobox
        QString Name = "XYZ";
        QIcon icon("Sample.png");

```
    myComboBox->insertItem(0, icon, Name);
```

Question is: When I insert using above method, it inserts the Icon at the left side(i.e.., Icon followed by Name) . 
How do I make the Icons to come at the Right Side(i.e.., First Name followed by Icon)

Regards
Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

`QComboBox` uses `QAbstractModel` for showing data. You can replace standard model with a custom one using function `void QComboBox::setModel ( QAbstractItemModel * model )`.

Icon position in relation to the text is controlled via style options. You should do something like this:

```
QStyleOptionViewItem option;
option.decorationAlignment = Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter;
option.decorationPosition = QStyleOptionViewItem::Top;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!!! QAbstractItemModel has 2 variants named "QAbstractTableView" and "QAbstractListView". Which one are you suggesting to use? How to apply the QStyleOptionViewItem to our custom model. Please post with an example. We tried to use "QAbstractListView" and in data() we added the code to return the QPixmap(For DecorationRole) and QString(DisplayRole). Still the Icons are not coming in the Right Side. How to apply the  QStyleOptionViewItem to our model

Comment: Oops. It turns out I've mixed up model's and view's code. All the code in the last part of my answer should be written in a view, so you cannot set this behavior to `QComboBox` via setModel. Sorry.

Comment: Can you please suggest solution for this problem. I need to show the Icons of the combo box items at the right side.

Comment: I looked through `QComboBox` source code, trying to solve your problem, but it turned out, that all the drawing occurs in its private implementation - `QComboBoxPrivate`, which practically does inheritance from `QComboBox` useless. The only solution I see is to write your own combo box, based on Qts source code, which is legal only if your program is open source, or you have bought commercial license of Qt.